# Api calls with rxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm using MVVM architecture, So basically this is my flow -

getting repository instance and return to Activity the result -

```
public MainViewModel() {
    moviesRepository = MoviesRepository.getInstance();
}

public LiveData<AllMovies> getAllMovies() {
    return moviesRepository.getAllMovies();
}
```

In my repository -

```
   private MoviesRepository() {
        allMoviesMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        getDataFromApi();
    }

private void getDataFromApi() {
    disposable.add(
            ApiService.getMoivesApi().getAllMovies()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<AllMovies>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AllMovies allMovies) {
                            allMoviesMutableLiveData.setValue(allMovies);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    })
    );
}
```

**I've 2 questions:**

**1)** This is my first time using rxJava, this is the correct flow of getting the response?

**2)** I'm using `disposable` to clear if there is a problem, and I should call in `onCleared` method, `dispoable.clear()`.
the problem is, that I haven't `onCleared` override method in my repository, so I can I clear this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planing to use RxJava + LiveDate there is no need to invent stuff that you can reuse.

Better approach is to use [LiveDataReactiveStreams](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams). In this case your repository doesn't need to handle LiveData.

```
Flowable<String> flowable = ... ;
LiveData<String> liveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(flowable);
```

Main issue is that you are return LiveData a result. Live data you exist inside of ViewModel and should not change it's instance. All you need is to update value of a [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData)

Comment: Actually this is look very intresting, So for example if I i use flowable for network call, it's automaticlly move this to different thread?

Comment: As @mohosyny mention use subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()). This way all work will be done in thread pull. Basically one of background threads.
Everything that will goes after .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) will run on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` instead of `Schedulers.newThread()`

and use `dispoable.clear()`  in Activity's `onPause()` method

check this : https://github.com/mohosyny/simpleMVP

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I basically run ```dispoable.clear``` where I actually call the function? How it is work, I created the dispoable  object in my repository, I haven't access it in my fragment/activites

Comment: look at this : https://github.com/mohosyny/simpleMVP
you'll learn how use RxJava